# Postfix rejecting emails [User unknown in virtual mailbox table;]

Tags: postfix

I have 3 domains hosted on a server, and two of them send/receive email fine, but the third rejects emails for some reason.

```
NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-lb0-f170.google.com[209.85.217.170]: 550 5.1.1 <chris@domain.com>: Recipient address rejected:     User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<me@gmail.com> to=<chris@domain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-lb0-f170.google.com>
```

The weird thing is that my other two domains recieve the email instantly, and all three are using the same MX record (mail.mydomain.com), and have equal dns records other than domain name.

I have checked that I can send receive when from localhost. Here is main.cf. I have heard about disbaling grey listing, but since the other two domains send/receive fine, I was hoping to get a better solution.

```
  7 #myorigin = /etc/mailname
  8 
  9 smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
 10 biff = no
 11 
 12 # appending .domain is the MUA's job.
 13 append_dot_mydomain = no
 14 
 15 # Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
 16 #delay_warning_time = 4h
 17 
 18 readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
 19 
 20 # TLS parameters
 21 smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
 22 smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
 23 smtpd_use_tls = yes
 24 smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
 25 smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
 26 
 27 # See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
 28 # information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
 29 
 30 myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
 31 alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
 32 alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
 33 myorigin = /etc/mailname
 34 mydestination = mail.mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
 35 relayhost =
 36 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
 37 mailbox_size_limit = 0
 38 recipient_delimiter = +
 39 inet_interfaces = all
 40 html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
 41 message_size_limit = 30720000
 42 virtual_alias_domains =
 43 virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
 44 virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
 45 virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
 46 virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
 47 virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
 48 virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
 49 smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
 50 broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
 51 smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
 52 smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
 53 virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
 54 virtual_maildir_extended = yes
 55 proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_do    mains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
 56 virtual_transport = dovecot
 57 dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, Im an idiot! I had a type in my mail database.

INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('sales@example.com', ENCRYPT('password'));